# Graphical environment issues in MATLAB R2019b. error g_memup2

Tags: linux, matlab, installation

When I run MATLAB (R2019b) from the command line I get this error:

> MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/glnxa64/jcef_helper: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_memdup2

Although MATLAB is working I cannot display the MATLAB documentation or the live scripts. Instead I obtain a black screen. When working with charts this warning appears:

> MATLAB has disabled some advanced graphics rendering features by switching to software OpenGL.

I have tried reinstalling the software but it does not work. I have also attempted other Stack Overflow solution but neither they work. I have looked for the symbol lookup error and I have realized this is a problem beetween libglib2.0-0 and libpango-1.0-0. I have updated both libraries and nothing works.

My operating system details:

```
Linux em-IdeaPad-3-14ITL6 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

My graphics device details:

```
em@em-IdeaPad-3-14ITL6:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.9 driver: X: loaded: vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting gpu: i915 resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz
    2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (TGL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1




>> opengl info
                          Version: '2.1 Mesa 17.1.3'
                           Vendor: 'Brian Paul'
                         Renderer: 'Mesa X11'
                   MaxTextureSize: 16384
                           Visual: 'Visual 0x6d, (RGBA 32 bits (8 8 8 8), Z depth 16 bits, Hardware acceleration, Double buffer, Antialias 0 samples)'
                         Software: 'true'
             HardwareSupportLevel: 'none (known graphics driver issues)'
        SupportsGraphicsSmoothing: 0
    SupportsDepthPeelTransparency: 1
       SupportsAlignVertexCenters: 0
                       Extensions: {152×1 cell}
               MaxFrameBufferSize: 16384
```

I am trying to learn how to fix issues with MATLAB graphical environment.

Comment: This seems like an installation issue, and nothing we can help with.  Reinstall and otherwise contact Mathworks

Comment: Just a hunch, but it's likely that a MATLAB released in 2019 was not tested with an Ubuntu release from 2022. You might have the wrong version of Pango library or some other dependency.